# Writing string to byte array in java

Tags: java

This has been bugging me for the last few hours.
I have a long string and I want to convert it to a byte array.
I want to preserve leading zeroes too.
Have tried DatatypeConverter & BigInteger methods and cant seem to get the proper result.
which is a byte array (of hex byte values).

```
byte[] array = str.getBytes();
```

This also doesn't seem to work, with all these methods I seem to be getting decimal representation of the string. I need it to be hex.

This is what I'm using at the minute:

```
String line;   
line = file.readLine();   
long seq = Long.parseLong(line);   
String hexx = Long.toHexString(seq);   
byte[] out = hexx.getBytes();
```

BTW, i am using BufferdReader for input and RandomAccessFile for output.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your question is not clear (what is a decimal representation of the string?). Add inputs expected outputs

Comment: Your leading `0`s are disappearing cause of `Long.parseLong()`

Comment: The input file is an ASCII file filled with number values.
I want the output to be a binary file.

Comment: Decimal representation means the string holds a number of ASCII characters, all numbers 0-9.

Comment: Can you give an example of the file you're trying to parse?

Comment: It is simply a text file containing random numbers.

Comment: So if the file contained `12345`, what should the byte representation be? Something like `[0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05]`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to convert from one radix to another. Jeez!

```
String str = ...
int fromRadix = ...
int toRadix = ...
String out = new BigInteger(str, fromRadix).toString(toRadix);
```

For example, to convert the decimal number "12345" to hex:

```
String str = "12345";
int fromRadix = 10;
int toRadix = 16;
String out = new BigInteger(str, fromRadix).toString(toRadix);
// yields "3039"
```

Go away!  :P

Comment: No, sorry. Maybe I was unclear, I want to convert the ENTIRE string from decimal to hexadecimal and write it to file.

Comment: What is in this string? A hex representation of a number (like "011ABF") or something like, "Hello, world"? If it's a hex number, this works.

Comment: Actual ASCII characters 0-9.

Comment: @resetter: And each individual character goes in its own byte, or is it two characters per byte?

Comment: I think two characters per byte, as it is written in hex.

Comment: @resetter: **what** is written in hex? the string or the bytes?

Comment: The bytes converted to hex from the (ASCII) decimal string.

Comment: In that case, preserving leading zeros would be meaningless because they represent different scalar values. I assume this is a homework assignment. Please give the question **exactly** as written.

Comment: Not an assignment. Its for a project I'm working on. This webpage has the thing I need written in javascript, so it can't be that difficult in java surely. (or php actually)
http://www.mobilefish.com/services/big_number/big_number.php

Comment: That page shows the **opposite** of what you asked for. It's encoding binary data (bytes) into ascii compatible text. Is that what you want? To covert binary numbers like `0101` into an encoded text string like "ufG9"? Or do you want to convert the encoded string back into binary?

Comment: Theres options to specify what conversion you want to make, DEC>HEX, HEX>DEC, etc.

Comment: Dude, you need to express yourself more clearly! If I knew where you were (and if I were meaner) I'd throttle you right now! So you just want to convert from one radix (base 16, base 10, etc) to another radix. That means you're converting from text to text. You just want a different text representation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have solved this by using BigInteger and it's toByeArray method.

```
  BigInteger linenum = new BigInteger(line,10);
  writer.write(linenum.toByteArray());
```

Actually simple solution, thanks for your efforts guys.

Comment: That doesn't do what you ask. See my (new) answer.